# R sample split column chosen

Tags: r, classification, sample

Im doing some classification problems and I found something "odd"

here is the code that Im running

```
set.seed(85)
split=sample.split(newauto$year,SplitRatio =1/2)
training_set = subset(newauto, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(newauto, split == FALSE)
modelo1=lda(mpg01~origin+year*weight+displacement,data=training_set)
lda.pred1=predict(modelo1,test_set)
lda.class1=lda.pred1$class
table(lda.class1,test_set$mpg01)
errorr=mean(lda.class1==test_set$mpg01)
```

What I noticed is that if I use different columns of newauto (data frame), the error rate change.Is this normal? I supposed that sample.split is only dependant of the seed and not of the column chosen

Thank you.

Comment: When you say *"use different columns"*, do you mean within `sample.split` or within `lda`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question might be better answered on stats.stackexchange as it relates more to the statistics of the algorithm than the code you are writing.

Comment: r2evans I mean with sample.split